# Is it possible to read an LLVM bitcode file into an llvm::Module?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, llvm

I'm writing a compiler with LLVM. Each source file is compiled into an LLVM bitcode file. Eventually the linker links and optimizes all the bitcode files into one final binary.

I need a way to read the bitcode files in the compiler in order to access the type information. The LLVM documentation shows a class called `BitcodeReader`, but that appears to be internal to LLVM.

Is there any publicly accessible way to read a bitcode file into an `llvm::Module`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I looked through the source to the `llvm-dis` tool and found the function I was looking for:

```
Module *ParseBitcodeFile(MemoryBuffer *Buffer, LLVMContext& Context,
                         std::string *ErrMsg = 0);
```

from `llvm/Bitcode/ReaderWriter.h`.

Comment: That's exactly what you need.